# I want to load php with a message to hide a form after submit but event.preventDefault(); ruins an "already exists" check on my .php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

After submitting there must exist 3 possible states:

1. Data saved and php message is loaded onto where the form was.
2. Data already exists and I load a different php informing the user.
3. An error occurred, show an alert asking the user to please try again.

This is what my submit .php looks like:

```
$test="select * from launchpage where email_launchPage ='$email'";
$testing=$link->query($test);
$alreadyExists=$testing->num_rows;

if($alreadyExists ==1){
    echo "<script>alert('already exists');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
} else{
    $sqlInsertListingType="insert into launchpage(email_launchPage,language_launchPage) values('".$email."','".$language."')";
    $link->query($sqlInsertListingType);
    echo "<script>alert('saved');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
}
```

It works fine on it's own and this is my try at an ajax request to submit:

```
$(document).on("submit","#form",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var formType = $(this).attr("method");
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: formType,
        data: formData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log('went through ajax');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("i've ruined something");
        }
    });
});
```

Which also works, but because of the .preventDefault(); I "don't" know if the data was saved or not.

I have no idea what I should try to do to bring these 2 together, or if there's a better way to do this...

I'm guessing this must be rather easy to solve, I'm just missing something I haven't learned yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return JS or other html. return some json:

```
<?php

... process form data
if (processing succeeds) {
   $msg = array(
       'code' = 1,
       'message' = 'Success'
   );
} else {
   $msg = array(
       'code' => 0,
       'message' => 'Failed, something dun blowned up'
   );
}
echo json_encode($msg);
```

Then in your success handler:

```
success: function(data) {
        if (data.code == 1) {
             do_success_stuff();
        } else {
            alert('requested failed with error #' + data.code + " and message '" + data.message + "'");
        }
 }
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, but I don't understand how I can use the json object on the ajax callback. The .php process if working as it should, but I'm always getting the alert as it can't see a data.code...

Comment: A console.log for just code.message just returns undefined.

Comment: One more update: I've understood how the json is returned. But I still don't understand how to "use it". Using data.code or data.message are always undefined so I can't use them for the if condition in my success handler. What am I missing? If I don't have a condition and just put alert(data) i can see the json, alert(data.key) or alert(data.message) are undefined.

Comment: Screw this, I'll just return a single value instead of an array. Got it working like this which is enough for this, maybe someday I'll need to return an array and when that happens I'll just look into this again.

In any case thanks a lot for your time. I got this working like I needed so I'm happy :)